# how to add multiple items in single invoice in access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have used following code from stack over flow

```
combobox AfterUpdate 
Private Sub InvoiceCombo_AfterUpdate()
If IsNull(Me.InvoiceCombo) Then
Me.Product=Null
Me.qty=Null
Me.Rate=Null
Else
Me.Product=me.InvoiceCombo.Column(1)
Me.Qty=me.InvoiceCombo.Column(2)
Me.Rate=me.InvoceCombo.Column(3)
End If
End Sub
```

this is working fine but the problem is cannot add multiple rows(multiple products, like multiple items in one invoice)